# Create toggle menu raw javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a little confused about how create a menu with raw javascript, pretty similar like [bootstrap dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) with those interactions:

- click on button and show dropdown
- click again and hide dropdown
- lose focus on dropdown and hide it

I was doing a series of tests and I couldn't find how bootstrap do it!

Somebody has any idea of how does it work?

This what I have:

HTML:

```
<!-- Menu button -->
<div class="flex align-items-center menu-btn">
    <i class="material-icons task-more flex justify-content-center align-items-center" data-toggle="hola">more_horiz</i>
</div>
<!-- Menu -->
<div class="task-menu">
    <div class="task-menu-item flex align-items-center">
        <i class="material-icons">alarm</i>
        <span>Alarms</span>
    </div>
    <div class="task-menu-item flex align-items-center">
        <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
        <span>Edit</span>
    </div>
    <div class="task-menu-item flex align-items-center">
        <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
        <span>Delete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Show-hie menu
Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('.task-more')).forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let menu = el.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.task-menu');
        menu.classList.toggle('display-block');
        menu.tabIndex = -1;
        menu.focus();
    });
});
// Hide on blur
Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('.task-menu')).forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('blur', function(){
        el.classList.remove('display-block');

    }, true);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/dropdown.js

Comment: Please add code snippet of work u have done around this and specific problem you are facing.

Comment: Thank you Phil! Let check that repository! @Phil

Comment: Ready @AmitBhoyar !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button id="drop" onclick="drop();">Drop down</button>
<div id="menu">
    <!-- content here-->
</div>
```

Script:

```
var button = document.querySelector('#drop');//or any other selector like getElementBy...
var menu = document.querySelector('#menu');
function drop() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        menu.style.display="block";
        button.setAttribute('onclick', 'hide();');
    }, 10);
};

 function hide() {};
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menu.style.display="none";
});
```

Comment: thanks! But is completely necessary to attach a click event to document? Because that can collide with another behaviors, right?

Comment: No, because you are adding an event listener, you can always add more & more 'click'-events. I have been using this for so long and have not experienced any issues/ problems with it. Besides you can always remove an eventListener if you'd like.